# Positioning issues between Chrome & Safari

Tags: css

I'm writing a basic start page for myself and it's looking great in Chrome, however the positioning is completely off in Safari (My daily driver on my laptop). In Chrome it's nicely centered both vertically and horizontaly, yet in Safari it's way off in the top right corner, looks like the bottom left corner is centered instead. Here's some screen grabs of it.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Safari:

[image: Safari]

Here's my CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);

*{
    margin: auto;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    background-color: #292929;
    color: #fff;

    position: relative;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

h2{
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a:hover{
    color: #0098bc;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

/* ----- Containters ----- */

#container{
    text-align: center;
    border: 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    width: 1000px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

#container li{
    padding: 10px;
}

#social_container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#entertainment_container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#news_container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#misc_container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New Tab</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="social_container">
                <h2>Social</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com">Reddit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linustechtips.com">Linus Tech Tips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.500px.com">500px</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="entertainment_container">
                <h2>Entertainment</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.netflix.com">Netflix</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.nowtv.com">Now TV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.vessel.com">Vessel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div
            >
            <div id="news_container">
                <h2>Reading</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news">BBC News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.theverge.com">The Verge</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.tested.com">Tested</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.chefsteps.com">ChefSteps</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="misc_container">
                <h2>Misc</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://mail.google.com">Gmail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.icloud.com">iCloud</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://email.myconnect.bbc.co.uk">BBC Mail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.deviantart.com">Deviant ART</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.overapi.com">OverAPI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&linkCode=ur2&tag=linustechtips-21">Amazon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on a solution to this?

Thanks, James.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Still doesn’t tell us anything useful, without knowing the HTML this gets applied to … please go read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a vendor prefix for Safari.

Change

```
#container{
    ...
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%); /* THIS LINE */
}
```

to

```
#container{
    ...
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

The reasons can be found here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Safari is the only "modern" browser still requiring a vendor prefix on the transform property.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of small issues with your css:

1) Set height of document to 100%

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

2) Position container centered

```css
#container{
    text-align: center;
    border: 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: The html and the body will collapse if they are not filled with content. To truly center something with css we need to start with a parent container that is the full size of the browser window.

Comment: I added this and its thrown my container div into the top left corner with the majority of it off screen :/

Comment: You need to keep your original css as well. These are additions/modifications. so in entirety for container would be `#container{
    text-align: center;
    border: 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}`